# Using weka to measure the quality of my classifier

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I programmed my own classifier in python, I used a text corpus to test it using F1 measurement, but now I want to test it in other Data Mining tasks, so I have my classifier output file to a given corpus and I want to measure the quality using Weka different measures, how I can past to Weka the output file and get the quality?

Comment: The problem is : if you trained your classifier and learned a model, you must serialized the model somehow in python.  To use it in weka, 1) weka needs to understand your classifier algorithm (i.e., is it compatible with weka's existing algorithms, J48, naive bayes etc. ?  2) weka needs to understand the model format in order to load it. I guess 1) might be ok in your case, but you need to work on 2).  probably can start from here: https://weka.wikispaces.com/Saving+and+loading+models

Comment: When I re-read you question, I found out that you actually want to just use weka's evaluation measures without prediction inside weka. I have no idea whether weka exposes such API so that you can pass in predicted labels and golden labels and then outputs different measures.

Comment: Yes, I actually want to just use weka's evaluation measures without prediction inside weka, I already have the predictions file of my algorithm, so I just want to use weka to measure the quality of it. I was looking in the web for a weka opcion and file prediction format or something like that but I didn't found it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct procedure should be some sort of n-fold validation: Divide your data set into training and test sets.  Develop the model on the training set; calculate its sum of squared errors SSE(train).

The take the model and run the test data through it and calculate the SSE(test) using the predicted and actual response values.  That'll help you assess the accuracy and bias of your model.

Have a look at [Elements of Statistical Learning Using R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/an-introduction-to-statistical-learning-with-applications-in-r/).

Comment: Is there any link that illustrates the procedure you mentioned before?